# Best place to load wp_ajax_the_ajax_hook action in plugin

Tags: plugins, ajax

I am building a shortcode plugin and I want to avoid loading unecessary code unless the shorcode is called in a page.

I am having trouble with the ajax functions. It seems I need to load everything very early in the plugin code, thus loading unecessary code for the whole site.

I am talking about the usual calls in adding ajax

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_the_ajax_hook', 'testFunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_the_ajax_hook', 'testFunction' );
```

and also the backend function needs to load.

```
function testFunction(){
        //do some server side thing with $POST
        echo 'this is a test function';
        die();
     }
```

If I don't load the add_action's at my plugin "top" code I don't get the ajax.js loaded
If I don't load the testFunction at my plugin "top" code I get a call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'testFunction' not found or invalid function name

I have no problem loading the scripts "on demand" when shortcode is called, that is:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', FAU_PLUGIN_URL . 'js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Hope someone has had this issue too... Thank you in advance

Comment: You could test a couple hooks with the conditional `has_shortcode()` but I'm not sure reliable that will be when adding hooks since you need actual `$post_content` to test against.

Comment: So you only want to add the ajax `add_action` and the `testFunction` if the shortcode exists on the page?

Comment: I think the problem is when did you call the wp_ajax hook, is it inside a function / class that's called on the file directly or through another hook? I think you will need to be more specific. When you need this ajax? or at least you can describe your code workflow

Comment: Thanks. I will try the has_shortcode, even if it's not 100% reliable, at least it performs better

Comment: @nackle - the ajax hook action was called in the shortcode function.

Comment: update: if I use the has_shortcode() with the code kindly provided by @ccprog the ajax.js is indeed loaded but it doesn't "see" the testFunction declaration no matter where I place it.

Comment: What does your ajax code look like? What happens if you go to `http://yoururl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=the_ajax_hook` in your browser

Comment: @czerspalace if I have the add_action( 'wp_ajax_the_ajax_hook', 'testFunction' ) in the "plugin top code it works (the server side function is called). But if I place it under a has_shortcode loaded in a add_action( 'get_header'.. it returns 0

Comment: That's the way AJAX works. When you make the AJAX call to the server, the server side code has no knowledge of what page you are on, and because of that the server has no idea what content the current page contains.

Comment: got it and thanks @czerspalace .... so I see no way of not loading this part of the plugin code blog-wide...

Comment: Its not a good practice to call `wp_ajax` on frontend. you should create your own endpoint for security & performance concern. https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/07/30/custom-ajax-endpoints-in-2-4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the 'best' place, but `get_header` is early enough to still enqueue scripts:

```
function at_set_header () {
    global $post, $has_the shortcode;

    if ( is_object( $post ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'shortcode_name') ) {
        $has_the_shortcode = true;
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', FAU_PLUGIN_URL . 'js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'at_set_header');
```

The `$has_the_shortcode` global might be usefull to decide about other resources at later stages.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it sucessfully loads the ajax handles, however the reponse is always 0 no matter where I declare the testFunction. I tried plugin top code, inside the at_set_header, etc, it just seems the script can't see the testFuncion declaration that way?

Comment: What does the JS Ajax call look like? It needs to be a request to `ajaxurl` with parameter `action=the_ajax_hook`

Comment: thank you @ccprog in my ajax.js <pre>jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, { 'action': 'the_ajax_hook', data:'da_data', value:content_id } ,
  function(response_from_the_action_function){
  
  console.log(response_from_the_action_function);
  }</pre>...

Comment: Looks good so far. BTW, the ajax action needs to be declared top-code, since on the ajax call the get_header action will never be executed. Can you assert whether your `testFunction` gets called or not? You could i. e. try to log something with `trigger_error`.

Comment: Hello @ccprog, I found that out too (also from czerspalace comment). So if I declare the ajax call blog-wide I have to declare the ajax php funcions too otherwise the function is never found by the ajax.js script when it loads.